# Retrieve Access Token from JSONResponse android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API to retrieve the access token of my facebook page..I used the code below to get a JSON respnse which contains the token for my facebook page.

```
 AccessToken token=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                token,
                "/me/accounts",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        // Insert your code here
                        try {

                         //what should I do here.....

                        }catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        request.executeAsync();
```

I got this JSON as response

```
 {
  "data": [
   {
    "access_token": "<access_token_is_here>",
    "category": "Clothing",
    "name": "<page_name_is_here>",
    "id": "<id_is_here>",
    "perms": [
    "EDIT_PROFILE",
    "CREATE_CONTENT",
    "MODERATE_CONTENT",
    "CREATE_ADS",
    "BASIC_ADMIN"
   ]
 }
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
  "before": "MjkzMDAyNzM0MTYwNTQ1",
  "after": "MjkzMDAyNzM0MTYwNTQ1"
    }
  }
}
```

My Question is..How can I get the accessToken from this JSON response? I know that I can get the token as String..But I need it as Access Token itself so that I can use it to post status onto my facebook page....I am a beginner in this so kindly Help me...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
     JSONObject response=new JSONObject(resp);

JSONArray data=response.getJSONArray("data");

       String accessToken="";

for(int i=0;i<data.lenght();i++){

JSONObject temp=data.getJSONObject(i);

if(temp.has("access_token"){

accessToken=temp.getString("access_token");

break;

}

}
```

Now you can also store it into sharedPref or sqlite wherever you want if you want to persist it.

Comment: `data` is a **JSONArray** and not a **JSONObject**.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @Ben: In what format/data type you are expecting the acessToken to be apart from string?

Comment: Can I change the first line to   JSONObject response=new JSONObject(resp.toString()); ??

Comment: @PrerakSola: If the accessToken is in string format I would not be able to use it in new Graph request right?? So I was hoping to store it in AccesToken datatype..

Comment: Yes create accessToken object from [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/)

Comment: There is no data type called `AccessToken` in Java. The response data will always be in primitive data types (string, int, bool, etc.). For the new graph request you will need to use the `AccessToken` class provided by the facebook sdk to create it's object and use it in next requests.

Comment: @NayanSrivastava  umm...sorry..but I did not understand anything from that..can I see an example for that?

Comment: Basically you have to store the data that you get in response and construct AccessToken Object when you from them.

Comment: @NayanSrivastava: Am I supposed to fill  in this **public AccessToken(String accessToken, String applicationId, String userId, Collection permissions, Collection declinedPermissions, AccessTokenSource accessTokenSource, Date expirationTime, Date lastRefreshTime)** ? with the details I get from response?

Comment: damn..I'll try tomorrow then...Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String accesstoken = response.getJsonArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("access_token");
```